# Seperating ArrayList items to a regular keyword group

Tags: java, minecraft

I started Java for plugin codding in minecraft. now I'm trying to add role names as prefix and show it in chat.

```
    ArrayList<String> userRoles = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(player.hasPermission("chat.rank.admin")){
        userRoles.add("[Admin]");
    } if(player.hasPermission("chat.rank.vip")) {
        userRoles.add("[VIP]");
    }

    event.setFormat(userRoles<>(1) + " " + player.getDisplayName() + "§7: " + msg);
// In this line, the expected output is "[Admin] user: msg" or both [Admin] [VIP] user: msg"
// But it gives "([Admin],[VIP]) user: msg" 
// I'm sure it has a simple solution but as I said, I'm new here. thanks from now
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'userRoles<>(1)' ?

Comment: `userRoles<>(1)` does not compile I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to create a list which only stores one value.

You might want to try creating a function that get the rank name of the player outside of your `PlayerChatEvent` listener.

Here's a demo code:

```java
    public String getPlayerRankName(Player p){
        if (p.hasPermission("chat.rank.admin"))
            return "[Admin]";
        else if (p.hasPermission("chat.rank.vip"))
            return "[VIP]";
        else 
            return "";
    }
```

And in your `PlayerChatEvent` event listener, call this function in your chat line:

```java
event.setFormat(getPlayerRankName(event.getPlayer()) + " " + player.getDisplayName() + "§7: " + msg);
```

Comment: I wanted to show multiple ranks like [VIP] [Miner] player. how can i do it?

Comment: So you want a type of rank, let's say the Premium ones (VIP, MVP, ...) and the level ones (Miner, Butcher, ...) ? It that is the case, you can create another function that get the level rank and apply the same pattern to the chat event format.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct to close this topic if it fits your requirements. Thanks !